# Multiple Ajax Request Being Sent to Server On Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have an UI where when someone clicks a button the system opens up a bootstrap model with some message & a yes or no button, if "No" button clicked the bootstrap just dismiss and when "yes" button clicked then ajax request is sent to server.

**The problem is** if i click the button three times and then dismiss the modal i.e click "No"  all three times in the dialogue then as expected no ajax request is sent but when the fourth time i click the button and click yes on the modal then a total of 4 requests are sent to server at same time i.e. somehow it remembers the last 3 click events. How can i streamline this ?

this is the code.

```
$('.js--acc-display').on('click','.js--verify', function () {
    var mode = $(this).data('mode');
    $conformDialogue.find('.modal-body').text('Custom Message');
    $conformDialogue.modal('show').on('click', '#js--conform-ok', function(e) {                
       $conformDialogue.modal('hide')
             //// Ajax Request Code Here /////
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common pitfall, a simpe solution could just be to hide the button while requesting. Or you use attribute "disabled" which will work for most browsers

```
$conformDialogue.modal('show').on('click', '#js--conform-ok', function(e) {  
   /* on click disable the button */              
   $('#js--conform-ok').attr('disabled', true);
   $conformDialogue.modal('hide');

         //// Ajax Request Code Here /////

        /* on ajax-end enable again  */
        $('#js--conform-ok').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: i don't think this can be a solution as this will create problems in UI and will achieve nothing !! anyways i created a separate plugin to work modal as a conformation dialogue !! and problem in this code was a silly mistake ...if u r interested i can explain you. thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey Gaurav, what do you mean it will achieve nothing? it will prevent multiple clicks on the button while loading, also how does it create a problem in UI ? I think it is very nice ui-wise that the button is disabled, which is a nice browser-built-in feature to show the user that the button is currently not enabled

Comment: i has solved it and reason was something else which i don't remember